# Android Alarm Receiver onReceive Network Request

Tags: java, android

I have an application that allows users to schedule alarms for medical treatments. For example, a user could schedule an alarm to remind them to take Tylenol at 8am on Monday, Wednesday and Friday.

This application also has a web portion where users can check in and add/edit treatments. What I need to do is each time an alarm is triggered, I need to check an API to make sure that treatment is still valid because between the time an alarm was scheduled and fired, a user could have deleted that treatment via the web app.

In my code, I have an alarm receiver class. In the onReceive method of that class I have something like this.

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {    

    API.entries(Calendar.getInstance().getTime(), new API.OnApiResponse<JSONObject>() {

        @Override
        public void onFailure(API.API_Error error) {
            new DefaultErrors(mContext, error);
        }

        @Override
        public void onSuccess(JSONObject result) { 
            mResult = result
        }
    }
}
```

Obviously onSuccess and onFailure are callbacks. What happens is these never fire and when I check mResult further down, it's null. So my question is, since a Receiver is supposed to be pretty light weight, is there something that is preventing this from calling back? Is there something that would prevent network comms in a receiver? This exact code is working several other places in the application but via activities.

Is there a better pattern for accessing API's or making network calls in a receiver?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `BroadcastReceiver`'s lifecycle ends pretty much as soon as the `onReceive()` method is done executing. This means that your `OnApiResponse` object is probably long dead by the time the callback finally occurs. The `mResult` object is null further on in the `onReceive()` method because the the callback hasn't yet happened, presumably due to the network operations in the `API.entries()` method executing asynchronously.

You'll need to implement the interface in a component that will still be alive when the callback happens. If you're starting an `Activity` upon the broadcast receipt, you could implement it there. If not, another option is to create a `Service` that can be started from the Receiver to execute the `API.entries()` call and await the callback, after which you can stop the `Service`.

Comment: Would it also be a good design, if I implemented the Service approach, to go ahead and check the api, build the alert, and manage some other things in there as well? Basically use the service as a helper to do all the things that aren't supposed to happen in the short life cycle of the receiver?

Comment: It definitely could be done there, and I almost edited my answer to say that. I could tell from your question, though, that you're knowledgeable enough to have seen that, so I didn't bother. Ultimately, it's up to you, and how you want to handle the separation of concerns in your design with the given objectives. FWIW, that's basically how I'd do it; keep as much out of the Receiver as possible, and anything that needs to happen asynchronously, or behind the scenes, would be handled in the Service.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally you should use an AsyncTask or IntentService, not a normal Service and not within the Activity.  Both of those will work, but the code there runs in the main application thread, which can result in ANRs if the web service is slow.

An IntentService is almost as easy to create as a standard Service, maintains its own thread to handle requests and avoid ANRs, and automatically shuts down as soon as it has no more intents to handle.

Comment: How do you propose to handle asynchronous callbacks in an AsyncTask or IntentService, given that both of those classes stop themselves soon after their main methods finish executing?

Comment: Without seeing how this API class actually works I can't offer a specific answer to this, but in my own apps, I use blocking calls with AsyncTasks and IntentServices.  For example, HttpURLConnection.

Comment: If the network transactions are already happening asynchronously, it's not going to block either a Service or an Activity. I guess it's ultimately up to the OP if they want to rewrite their network ops, if that would be needed.